# What's the appropriate Stack Exchange site for asking about setting up dual monitors?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have tried every solution given on the Internet, as well as some tricks up my own sleeve.

Nothing works to help me "extend" my desktop and not "duplicate" it across 2 monitors.

My question is "What is the appropriate site to ask about this?" I don't think it would be Stack Overflow, but I don't dare try any of them for fear of being downvoted to death if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JonW Thanks for showing me the "site-rec" tag. Definitely needed that one :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the appropriate site.  You're asking about how to effectively utilized existing software.  That's exactly what the site is there for.

Note that while it's on topic there, check their FAQ to ensure it meets all of the other guidelines for being a valid post on that site.  They get a lot of crap there, so plan accordingly and ensure the question is of high quality.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Also, it shouldn't be any worries on me asking the question with decent quality. I have SO to thank for all of the practice I've had with that :) Thanks, again, Brother :)

Answer (score 3):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) should work. If your OS is Ubuntu or Linux based, you can try [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) for a more focused answer.

Comment: As if any other organization could botch up what would otherwise be a simple program, other than Microsoft. :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am definitely a Windows user and not a Linux user (I like Windows most of the time...). But when I can't get something to work in Ubuntu, etc. It's because I don't know enough about the labyrinth of configurations and technical solutions it takes to do even the most menial of tasks (this is the problem I have with Linux), however, that is still a lack of knowledge on MY part. At least when the Linux community writes a program, it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @VoidKing: Ha. I use both, though recently I've been sticking to Linux. Some of my non-technical-savvy friends use Linux though, and they've not had that problem. Windows restricts you quite a bit. Linux GUI restricts you the same amount. But Linux via the command line is extremely powerful and since there are scripts on the Internet it's no big deal :)